# How to find out why GPS coordinates are missing in Android?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get a device's location information using GPS, but for some reason one of the two coordinates is missing sometimes.

This is the code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
Log.d("LOCATION1", "Longitude: " + longitude);
Log.d("LOCATION2", "Latitude: " + latitude);
```

Sometimes I do get both coordinates, but not always, which makes me think about some kind of delay somewhere. Is there a way to find out **why** a GPS coordinate is missing when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the GPS isn't always on.  getLastKnownLocation will return a location *if it knows one* and if it isn't too stale.  Since nothing else was using the GPS, it doesn't know one.  If you need a location, either requestLocationUpdates or requestSingleUpdate, which will turn on the GPS and get a new location.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I should still call `getLastKnownLocation` after `requestSingleUpdate` though, right?

Comment: You don't need to.  requestSingleUpdate has a callback parameter, it will call you when it has a result (it takes some time for GPS to start up, it needs to talk to satelites).  You can call  GLKL and see if it just so happens to have a stored location so you can display it quicker, you just can't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
   // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney2).title("fi"));
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true), 2000, 0, new android.location.LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           // 
        }
```

in onLocationChanged method you can use **location.getLatitude & location.getLongitude**